# Extract .rar file in Vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel, unrar

I have a vba macro in Excel which download a .rar file from a sharepoint site and extract it. The downloading is working fine, i can see the file downloaded in the folder but extracting the file is not working.
I will paste just the part of extracting the file so my code looks like this

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim RarIt As String
    Dim Source As String
    Dim Desti As String
    Dim WinRarPath As String

    WinRarPath = "C:\Program Files\WinRar\"
    Source = "C:\Reports\EMEA Load.rar"
    Desti = "C:\Reports\"

    RarIt = Shell(WinRarPath & "WinRar.exe e " & Source & " " & Desti, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

so when i run it, it returns a message box "no archives found" although i can see the .rar file in the folder.

I have created another solution, a function which unzip files

```
Function Unzip(str_FILENAME As String)

    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim Fname As Variant
    Dim FnameTrunc As Variant
    Dim FnameLength As Long
    Dim FnamePath As Long

    Fname = str_FILENAME
    FnamePath = InStrRev(Fname, "\")
    FnameTrunc = Left(Fname, FnamePath)

    Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.Namespace(FnameTrunc).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(Fname).Items

End Function
```

and i am calling this function in my Sub, it works fine for .zip files but for .rar file it returns this error

> "method of Namespace object ishelldispatch6 failed"

```
Sub Extract2()

    Dim strFilePath As String
    strFilePath = "C:\Reports\EMEA Load.rar"

     Unzip (strFilePath)

End Sub
```

Any suggestions please what i need to change in my code ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Try : `RarIt = Shell(Chr(34) & WinRarPath & "WinRar.exe" & Chr(34) & " e " & Chr(34) & Source & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Desti & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)`

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now

Comment: @Fadi post your comment as an answer ;) JuniorDev: for your second solution it doesn't work since Windows can't extract rar natively.

Comment: @JuniorDev, You are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we have spaces in files name we need to enclose it by `Chr(34)` :

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim RarIt As String
    Dim Source As String
    Dim Desti As String
    Dim WinRarPath As String

    WinRarPath = "C:\Program Files\WinRar\"
    Source = "C:\Reports\EMEA Load.rar"
    Desti = "C:\Reports\"

    RarIt = Shell(Chr(34) & WinRarPath & "WinRar.exe" & Chr(34) & " e " & Chr(34) & Source & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Desti & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```